# Returning the list of files to Main Method for further processing the files

Tags: java

The program returns list of files in a directory `file[] fList`. Im unable to return list of file to `public static void main(String[]agrs)`, so that i can use each file a parse it.

I'm beginner in java.. 
My code so far:-

```
public class FileList {

    private static final String files = null;
    //Directory path here

    public String ListFile(String files) {
        String path = "/Users/";
        File folder = new File(path);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
                if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                    files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
                    if (files.endsWith(".xml")) {
                        System.out.println(files);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return files;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileList fl = new FileList();
        fl.ListFile(files);
    }
}
```

and the method

```
public File[] listf(String directoryName) {
        String files = "";
        File directory = new File(directoryName);
        // get all the files from a directory
        File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < fList.length; i++) {

            if (fList[i].isFile()) {
                files = fList[i].getName();
                if (files.endsWith(".xml")) {
                    System.out.println(files);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(fList);
        return fList;
    }
```

Comment: Where is your `public static void main`.. I mean how you are calling this function?

Comment: Im calling this in the same..class

Comment: Show the code of calling.

Comment: public class FileList {
 private static final String files = null;

 // Directory path here

 public String ListFile(String files) {
  String path = "/Users/";
  File folder = new File(path);
  File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
  {
   for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
     files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
     if (files.endsWith(".xml")) {
      System.out.println(files);
     }
    }
   }
  }
  return files;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  FileList fl = new FileList();
  fl.ListFile(files);
  
 }
}

Comment: I assume that im making some mistaking while calling the file list into main program.

Comment: are you sure you are calling `listf` using `fl.ListFile(files);`

Comment: Yes.. I should not be using it.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this program with changes stated in comments it works..

```
import java.io.File;


public class Demo
{

     private static final String files = null;
        //Directory path here

       /* public String ListFile(String files) {
            String path = "My/";//Use pathname like this
            File folder = new File(path);
            File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
                    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                        files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
                        if (files.endsWith(".xml")) {
                            System.out.println(files);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return files;
        }
    */
    public File[] listf(String directoryName) {
        String files = "";
        File directory = new File(directoryName);
        // get all the files from a directory
        File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < fList.length; i++) {

            if (fList[i].isFile()) {
                files = fList[i].getName();
                if (files.endsWith(".xml")) {
                    System.out.println(files);
                }
            }
        }

        //System.out.println(fList);//Not needed
        return fList;
    }




  public static void main (String[] args) {
  File f[]=new File[10];
  f=new Demo().listf("My");
    //new Demo().ListFile(files);//it just prints file names

//for(int i=0;i<f.length;i++)
   // System.out.println(f[i].getName());
  }

}
```

Comment: Ask Thakare.. This work but.. in this there are 2 programs.   public File[] listf(String directoryName)  and public String ListFile(String files) on comment either of code.. program.. file.. how ever i have only xml file in my directory.. Suggest the changes plzz

Comment: Yes i just want list of xml files in Main method.

Answer (score 0):

You attempt to access an instance method from a `static` context.

You have two (basic) options.

1. Create an instance of the class where the method resides and access the method via the instance or
2. Make the method `static`, for example, `public static File[] listf(String directoryName) {`

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the files by using absolute path. E.g. "D:\Folder1\Folder2". Also, instead of using "\", use `File.Separator`.